# SQL Server - Constructing a Column Definition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to compare two databases and identify what columns have changed. Once I have identified a column that has changed in some way (size, type, etc) I need to capture (write to a table) the old column definition and the new column definition.

For instance, if using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table I discover that a column size has changed from 25 to 50 I will need to store the two column definition. In this case it may be 'char(25)' and 'char(50)'.

I have not problem using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table to identify when something has changed.

The issue I have is once I determine that the column has changed how do I build the column definition? In this case how to I build 'char(25)' and 'char(50)'?

Is there somewhere I can obtain this type of definition? If I have to build the definition piece by piece how do I determine all the components of the definition.

Any advice or suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you realize there are a myriad of tools on the market that will do schema comparisons for you, and create synchronization scripts to update the target, to make it equal to the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select table_name, column_name,
column_definition = data_type + isnull('(' + convert(varchar, character_maximum_length) + ')', '') 
from information_schema.columns
```